# Does solid state maser exist?

Tags: led, radio, laser

In my student years we studied the microwave quantum device, equivalent to laser, named maser. It worked on ammonia molecules, so it was not a solid state. It has phenomenal specs, as quantum device is supposed to. The noise, amplification and the selectivity.

With decades of development in solid state lasers, and solid state acoustics/mechanics, did similar development ever happened to masers ? Or is there fundamental low frequency limit for quantum SSD ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to exists as [this 1970(!) book](http://books.google.com/books?id=u9a6AAAAIAAJ&source=gbs_similarbooks_r&cad=2) shows. (I guess it would be a very thin book otherwise).

I found also some [IEEE documents](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=mozclient&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&q=site%3aieeexplore.ieee.org+%22solid+state+maser%22) on Solid State MASERs. Only accessible for members.

Comment: Wow. nice surprise. Looks like whole another alternative dimension of electronics was invented and lost in the past

Comment: @RS - Lost? I don't know. We barely touched the subject in college, at least I don't remember. What would you expect the Solid States would be used for?

Comment: I just read quickly about electron paramagnetic resonance. There are only few multimeters in the world built for big labs to study 1-40GHz things. Strange. they complain that can not make magnets strong enough ot something

Answer (score 0):

Here's a book from 1964:  [Microwave solid-state masers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006AYLEU) (McGraw-Hill electrical and electronic engineering series) by  A. E Siegman

Comment: Nice find, thank you. Looks like he is some rocket scientist from Stanford. I will give credit to steventh also, he confirmed device existence first